# Change color in a particular area of border-bottom upon hover

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to recreate an effect that can be seen in the top links of http://math.stackexchange.com. The effect is that there is some text and a line below, upon hover both the text and segment of line below it changes color.

Here is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/4m7zc/ I tried making the bottom borders overlap but it didn't work. What is the appropriate way to do this?

HTML

```
<div class="top-links text-center">
<a href=# class="top-link">TEA </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href=# class="top-link">COFFEE </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href=# class="top-link">SODA </a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<a href=# class="top-link">ALCOHOL </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.top-links {
font-size:16px;
color: #b77b48;
border-bottom: 4.5px solid #db9356;

}

a.top-link {
color: #b77b48;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
border-bottom: 4.5px solid #db9356;
}

a.top-link:hover {
color: red;
margin-bottom:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
border-bottom: 4.5px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/4m7zc/4/

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/dC8P2/3/. it works 100% and check my answer which also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to copy the site exactly, you can use a list with `text-align:center` set on the `ul` then `display:inline-block` set on each `li`. Then simply apply a border on mouse hover to any links, and offset their bottom margin by the border width so they dont 'pop' out of place. Simple!

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCYd5/1/)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Link</a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li:hover a {
    color: #d02027;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #d02027;
    margin-bottom:-3px;
}
a {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
li {
    padding: 0 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following:

- Display your links as `inline-blocks`,
- Position them relatively, changing `top` to the same as your border height,
- Use a whole integer for your border, to avoid any rounding issues:

```
a.top-link {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:4px;
    color: #b77b48;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #db9356;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4m7zc/6/)

If the 4px of space above your buttons is bugging you, you can combat this by giving a -4px top margin to the parent:

```
.top-links {
    /* other styles */
    margin-top:-4px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4m7zc/7/)

Note: Don't use `&nbsp` to create margins between elements. That is what the CSS property `margin` is for.

Answer (score 1):

remove the underline from `a` tag using `text-decoration` property like below, so it looks similar to what you expect (Instead of aligning the line better to remove
)

```
a {
  text-decoration: none
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4m7zc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this>>>>[**DEMO JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dC8P2/3/)

I removed the text-decoration from the a element then I rearranged the order of the code and added some CSS and HTML so the navigation doesn't mix up with the line as it can be seen in the jsfiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="top-links text-center">
   <a href=# class="top-link">&nbsp;NEWEST&nbsp;</a>
<div class="line">|</div>
   <a href=# class="top-link">&nbsp;POPULAR&nbsp;</a>
<div class="line">|</div>
   <a href=# class="top-link">&nbsp;TAGS&nbsp;</a>
<div class="line">|</div>
   <a href=# class="top-link">&nbsp;USERS&nbsp</a>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.top-links {
font-size:16px;
color: #b77b48;
/*border-bottom: 4.5px solid #db9356;*/
}

a.top-link {
color: #b77b48;
border-bottom: 4.5px solid #db9356;
}

a.top-link:hover {
color: red;
border-bottom: 4.5px solid red;
}

.line {
display:inline;border-bottom: 4.5px solid #db9356;
margin:-4px;
}

a {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

Check the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dC8P2/2/ --if you need more help or this does not work please comment back. **This works 100%**.

Answer (score 1):

Please you this HTML - it more accurate

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Coffee</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Soda</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Alcohol</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#nav li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
#nav a {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #f00;
}
```